# Animation works only once when I click on image

Tags: javascript

I have a list of 3 thumbnail images
and a big one which stores any of these thumbnails I click

I also  have an animation that pops up big image from right side when I click on one of those thumbnail images

The problem is when I click one of those images, animation triggers only when I click thumb-img first time. then animation doesn't work

```js
let images = document.querySelectorAll('.thumb-img');
let main = document.querySelector('.main-img');
images.forEach((img) => {
  img.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    RemoveActive();

    main.src = img.src;
    main.classList.add('active');
    main.classList.add('active');
  });
});

function RemoveActive() {
  images.forEach((img) => {
    img.classList.remove('active');
    main.classList.remove('active');
  });
}
```

```css
.active {
  animation: 1s animate;
}

@keyframes animate {
  from {
    margin-right: -100%;
  }
  to {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="thumb">
  <li><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/94K19rp3/pepsi001.png" class="thumb-img" alt="" /></li>
  <li><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/r04jNMnD/pepsi002.png" class="thumb-img" alt="" /></li>
  <li><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/7JyVBddm/pepsi003.png" class="thumb-img" alt="" /></li>
</ul>
<div class="imgbox">
  <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/94K19rp3/pepsi001.png" class="main-img" alt="" />
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please update it with images from for example placeholder.com so we have a [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove your `active` class after animation is done so it will reset on another click.

```
let images = document.querySelectorAll('.thumb-img');
let main = document.querySelector('.main-img');

images.forEach((img) => {
  img.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    
    images.forEach(one => {
    one.classList.add('disabled');
 
      setTimeout(() => {
      one.classList.remove('disabled');
     }, 1000) // to prevent users from clicking while there is an animation
    })
    
    main.classList.remove('active');
    main.src = img.src;
    main.classList.add('active');
    
    setTimeout(() => {
      main.classList.remove('active');      
     }, 1000) // to match with css animation time
  });
});
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/KaungKZ/pen/OJRqoPm)